# Stability and Rate of Formation of Carbocations

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Consider the dehydration reaction of the following compounds with $\ce{H2SO4}$:

> (a) Tert-butyl alcohol
> (b) 3-Methylbut-2-en-1-ol

Consider the protonation of the $\ce{OH}$ group followed by the removal of a water molecule. In (a), we get a tertiary carbocation whereas in (b) we get a primary allylic carbocation. As far as I know, a tertiary carbocation is more stable than a primary allylic carbocation. Therefore I expect (a) to be dehydrated at a faster rate.

But if I consider a resonating structure of the carbocation formed in (b), I get a tertiary allylic carbocation which is more stable than the tertiary carbocation.

My main question is when comparing the rate of reaction of 2 different compounds, do we rank them based on the stability of the initial carbocation formed, or based on the most stable carbocation formed by these compounds after resonance?

I believe that the compound having the tertiary carbocation would be formed at a faster rate as the initially formed intermediate is more stable.

Could anyone please shed some light on this?

Comment: Rank it based on the stability of carbocation formed before rearrangement.

Comment: I think you're missing a locant for the alcohol.

Comment: I changed it. Could you please check now